# BCH from Poloniex

Tags: blockchain.info, bitcoin-cash

I had a BTC balance with Poloniex prior to the fork and I now have BCH too.

I wish to withdraw the BCH from Poloniex however am unsure of where it can be withdrawn to. Previously I have created BTC paper wallets using bitaddress.org. Can I create a paper wallet for BCH too?

I have a blockchain.info wallet however would like to maintain my private keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitcoin and BCH share the same private key and address system, so bitaddress.org should work fine (provided you ensure it's the legit version, and use it on a secure computer).

You can also use a wallet client like Electron Cash.

Ensure that you do not send the BCH to a segwit address (starting with bc1) or a P2SH-P2WPKH segwit address (starting with 3).

Multisig addresses starting with 3 will work fine, but ensure that it is a multisig address before sending it.

Comment: OK & thanks. Does this mean that if I have an old BTC paper wallet I can send my BCH to that same address?

Comment: Yes, you could. To redeem it, you would just need to import that private key into a BCH wallet like Electron Cash, instead of a BTC one like Electrum cash.

Comment: Just to be 100% sure... :) I can withdraw BCH to a BTC address and store it there?

Comment: As long as the BTC address is not segwit, yes